# Find the canonical form of quadratic form $x_1x_2-4x_1x_4+3x_2x_3+5x_2x_4-x_3x_4$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

> Find the canonical form of quadratic form $$x_1x_2-4x_1x_4+3x_2x_3+5x_2x_4-x_3x_4$$

I got the following expression:
$$x_1x_2-4x_1x_4+3x_2x_3+5x_2x_4-x_3x_4 =$$$$= (x_1+\frac{1}{2}x_2-2x_4)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(x_2-3x_3+5x_4)^2+\frac{9}{4}(x_3-\frac{2}{9}x_4)^2-x_1^2-\frac{328}{81}x_4^2$$
But might one have more square terms than the number of the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must have $\pm 1$ or zero on the diagonal, multiply my $D$ on both sides by
which changes the relation to $ (PR)^T H(PR) = D_1 $

$$ R =
\left(  
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \sqrt 2  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{40}} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &    \frac{ \sqrt{40} }{ 11 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 5 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 13 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 10 }  & 1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 40 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
1 & 0 & 3 & 5 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 4 & 5 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 5 &  -  \frac{ 13 }{ 8 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 4 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 10 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 40 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 40 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 121 }{ 40 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 3 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 40 }  & 1 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 9 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 40 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 121 }{ 40 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 3 &  - 9 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 40 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
1 & 0 & 3 & 5 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 4 & 5 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Is it a reversed solution? :)

Comment: @VIVID see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr